# Import email contacts (Gmail Yahoo Hotmail) using CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp, gmail, yahoo, hotmail

Is there any ready to use cakephp plugin or component to import Gmail, Yahoo and Hotmail contacts, so I can send invitations to user's friends?

If not, what is the easy way to do it, I am novice to cakephp so, a step by step tutorial would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by taking a look at [OpenInviter for CakePHP](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Kainchi/2010/03/08/openinviter-for-cakephp-2). Alternatively, for hosted solutions:

- [InviteBox](http://invitebox.com/) (beta, but you can request invite)
- [Free Tell-A-Friend](http://www.freetellafriend.com/)